# Custom theory solver for order theory?

Tags: z3

My program, bounded synthesizer of reactive finite state systems,  produces SMT queries to annotate a product automaton of the (uninterpreted) system and a specification. Essentially it is a model checking with uninterpreted functions. If the annotation exists => the model found by Z3 satisfies the spec. The queries contain:

- datatype (to encode states of a system and of a specification automaton)
- >= (greater), > (strictly) (to specify ranking function of states of automaton system*spec, which is used to search lassos with bad states)or in other words, ordering of states of that automaton, which
- uninterpreted functions with boolean domain and range
- all clauses are horn clauses

An example is https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/444947/posts/full_arbiter2.smt2
('forall' are used to encode "don't care" inputs to functions)

Currently queries take strictly greater `>` operator from integers arithmetic (that is a ranking function has `Int` range).

**Question**: is it worth developing a custom theory solver in Z3 for such queries? It could exploit DFS based search of lassos which might be faster than integers theory solver (or diff-neg tactic).

Or Z3 already efficiently handles this? (efficiently means "comparable to graph-based search of lassos").

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arithmetic is not the bottleneck of your benchmark.
We can check that by using

```
valgrind --tool=callgrind z3 full_arbiter2.smt2 
kcachegrind
```

Valgrind and kcachegrind are available in most Linux distros. 
So, I don't think you will get a significant performance improvement if you implement a solver for order theory. 
One bottleneck is the datatype theory. You may get a performance boost if you encode the types Q and T using Bit-vectors. Another bottleneck is quantifier reasoning. Have you tried to expand them before invoking Z3?
In Z3, the `qe` (quantifier elimination) tactic will essentially expand Boolean quantifiers.
I got a small speedup by replacing

```
(check-sat)
```

with

```
(check-sat-using (then qe smt))
```

Comment: thaanks! It took a while to collect data. In brief: 1) `qe` (and manual expansion) helps a lot (~10x) 2) why datatypes is a bottleneck? 3) switching to bv doesn't really help. See this 'report': https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/444947/posts/stackoverflow_orders_theory/profile_of_synthesis_queries.html

Comment: The datatypes were implemented with recursive structures (e.g., tree and lists) in mind. The implementation influences how choices are made by the search engine. For example, given a list term `t`. It will always "guess" first that `t` is `nil`. There is no optimization for finite datatypes such as enumeration types. Several users reported they perform poorly when used to encode enumeration types like `Q` and `T` in your formula. They reported they got a good speedup when they replaced the datatypes with bit-vectors (or integers with explicit bounds). It may be worth to try with integers.

Comment: (updated the table) On these small set of examples, `int` and `bv` are comparable to `dt`, but I will keep your suggestion in mind, thanks!